# Custom CSS for Google Sign In Button

Tags: google-signin

I'm stuck trying to style the Google Sign In Button while using the new API.

With the old, soon to be deprecated, version it was possible but as of March 2023 Google no longer wants you to use that version.

Is there really no other way? Do you have to choose between the white, blue or black button/icon?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried using the code generator, but it also is limited to the three choices of white, blue or black.